# Get values from JSON to create markers on a Google map

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am going to parse values/coordinates via AJAX and display as marker on a Google map.

AJAX code

```
$.each(data.Level, function(i, Level) {  
    $.each(Level.route, function(index, route) {
        // alert(route.lat)       
        myLatlngcc = new google.maps.LatLng(route.lat, route.lgn);
        var markercc = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlngcc,
            map: map
        });
        markers.push(markercc);
    });
```

JSON

```
{
    "Level": [
        {
            "route": [
                {
                    "lat": 39.105251,
                    "lgn": 26.551727
                },
                {
                    "lat": 39.105247125,
                    "lgn": 26.551774625
                }...
            ],
            "balls": [
                {
                    "lat": 39.105239375,
                    "lgn": 26.551869875
                },
                {
                    "lat": 39.10524325,
                    "lgn": 26.55182225
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "route": [
                {
                    ........
                },
                {
                    .....
                }...
            ],
            "balls": [
                {
                    ........
                },
                {
                    .....
                }...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get only the `lat` and `lgn` objects included in the array `route[1]`. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var json = { /* Your object */ }
var lat = json.Level[0].route[1].lat;
var lgn = json.Level[0].route[1].lgn;
```

Assuming you need the `lat` and `lgn` from each element in the `Level` array, you'll just need to place the above in a loop.

Comment: @user2352548 it's just straightforward access of an array. See this link for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array